# Correct way to ensure that a C++ DLL is deployed with a Windows Phone app

Tags: c++, dll, windows-phone-8

Using Visual Studio 2013, I have created a Windows Phone (8) app which references a Windows Phone Runtime Component which in turn references a C++ DLL (all in the same solution). Without doing anything explicitly, the DLL would not get deployed to the target platform, and so there would be a runtime error as the runtime component attempted to load the DLL. I got around the problem by adding the DLL (the DLL project output) as an additional deployable file to the runtime component project. (As one might add any other data file)

While my hack works, I'm sure it is not the correct thing to do... because it is a reference to the debug DLL (no release DLL built thus far), and if I were to do a release build for the solution, the same debug DLL would be deployed, where it ought to be the release version.

What is the proper/best practice way to ensure that the correct (debug vs release) "sub" project DLL gets deployed with a phone app?

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to include the dll project in your solution and than in the References of the Solution Explorer via the opening dialog.